# a 'module' must have a non-null XmlNamespace under BPEL4WS compliance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I am making a new biztalk solution, where i am using existing maps, schemas and orchestrations. And the orchestrations is giving me lots of problems.

I get this erorr message when I try to build my orchestration:

> a 'module' must have a non-null XmlNamespace under BPEL4WS compliance

I can't find any solution to it anywhere, so I hope somebody can help me here.
What does that error mean and how do I solve it??

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that if I clicked on the Project name, there is a BPEL Compliance that was set to True. Should have been set to false.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look familiar at all.

Right click on the project and hit properties. Check to see if your assembly namespace and name are set in the 'Application' tab.

Open the orchestration and click on the background between the port surfaces. Check the namespace in the properties window.

If that doesn't work perhaps you can temporarily remove items from the orchestration to see if you can isolate which shape is causing the error.

I have had very strange issues where the orchestration namespace was incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for the late repley. Had some other projects. Even with a totally empty orchestration, it gives me the sam error.

Answer (score 0):

Some projects require the BPEL Compliance setting to be true. For those projects you may have two cases:

1. If you do **not** wish to export the orchestration as a module; make sure the **Module Exportable** setting is ***false***.
2. If you wish to export the orchestration as a module; make sure the **Module Exportable** setting is ***true*** *together* with a **Module XML Target Namespace** setting that has a valid value instead of being empty (or null)